# fs.write(); fs.flush(); When is it really written to disk? What if kernel-panic or power outage?

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, atomic, hard-drive

I need to implement some atomic writes to secondary storage. How can I make this fool proof?

If I open a C# file handle using File.Open I will receive a handle. I can write some data to it. Flush it and close it. But I still have some questions. I guess the below statements are true?

- Data might not be written to disk but rather exist in the Windows Disk cache
- Data might not be written to disk but rather exist in the HDD cache

And this will lead to the following issues:

- A power outage will make the edits in the file I made reverted (On a transactional FS like NTFS)
- A kernel-panic will make the edits in the file I made reverted (On a transactional FS like NTFS)

Am I correct in my assumptions? If so, how can I make a fool proof write to the disk?
I have looked a little bit into NoSQL and have been thinking there might be a nosql server that could talk to the system closer to the hardware and not return to me software until it can guarantee that the bytes are written to disk.

All ideas and thoughts are welcome

Jens

[edit]
Maybe there is a specific amount of time I can wait before being sure that all changes are written to physical disk?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make an operation fully "fool proof" is queue, run the operation, and confirm. Things stay in queue and can be run again, until confirmed, or if the confirmation is negative "rolled back".

The window of time you are talking about, assuming you are not involving a network (everything is local), is very small. Still, if you want to ensure things, you queue them. MSMQ is one option. If the data comes from SQL Server, you can consider it's queueing mechanism Service Broker (not recommending this direction, but it is one way).

Ultimately, the idea here is a lot like a handshake, as used in most server to server communication. Everyone agrees things are done before both sides get rid of their piece of the work.

Comment: It's worth noting that MSMQ has a 4MB limit - so you're going to be limited in how large your queued files can be.

Comment: If you are talking large amounts of data, you may end up with a custom queue.

Comment: Are you really sure about this? That an MSMQ would work? What magic does an MSMQ do that I cant do in c# itself? I would prefer not using MSMQ because I have very bad experiences with it from earlier projects. Being extremely slow in a virtual environment and I need something I can keep sorted.

Comment: How can I confirm that the changes are written to disk? If they are in disk cache I guess that I can read it and it will actually be fetched from the cache and not from the disk? How can I ever verify that "things are done" so that I can get rid of the piece of work on the other end?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Windows internals, but I believe you are correct.  I didn't test it in great detail, but was able to use MSMQ as a pretty reliable place to store data, with another process that monitored the queue for final processing.